# SVG moving header image

Tags: html, css, svg

I installed a plugin to put a shop on my webpage (https://www.irelandsfuture.com/store) but because of that it moves my header down as you can see only on that page.

Someone gave me a tip that it was due to this being added which I think comes from the plugin:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" display="none">
```

but it should be using this below but in the CSS of the plugin provided I can't see the previous text occurring to amend it to the below.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style=" display: none;">
```

Given the plugin CSS below how do I fix this issue in Wordpress please even if I need to add custom CSS somewhere to do it?

Thanks

Plugin CSS here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_qf546KF0RCKRTJKJSpH9NE9VqnLIo8/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: `style="display: none;"` will make the SVG not to be display at all. `display="none"` is not valid.

Comment: Fair enough, any tips on how to avoid this big gap above my header? Thanks

Comment: I answered, hope it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely an issue with the plugin's externally loaded JS scripts; it's including an svg element with "display='none' which is not valid syntax. [Spreadshop Plugin v1.6.2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/spreadshop/)

As a quick fix from your end, add the following CSS. Note this may change based on other html changes you make, it just so happens that currently the div to hide is the first one (and as no specific class/id to reference).

```
body > div:first-of-type { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Legend, that worked, I didnt put it in the plugin code but the custom css of wordpress. So so happy, thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Add class to the div container:

```
<div class="header">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
</div>
```

In the CSS:

```
.header {
   display: none;
}
```